# Execute command in variable with bash through ssh

Tags: bash, variables, ssh

I face an issue while sending a command to a local variables in ssh. Actually my variable doesn't receive the expected execution of the coding instructions.
If someone has an idea about the good syntax to be applied...

```
ssh -T $HR_HST -l $HR_USR -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <<END_SSH_0
HermesShowCmd="sfe in;fname=$INPUT_WPPComOutFile;node=$Node;format=1" #ok
$HermesFolder/hcl \$HermesShowCmd >> $HR_LOG/$HRM_LOG #ok
HermesStatus=`$HermesFolder/hcl "$HermesShowCmd" | grep "Taken:    \.\.\." | wc -l` #KO... variable not updated...
echo "$(date) --HermesStatus=\$HermesStatus" >> $HR_LOG/$HRM_LOG
END_SSH_0
```

Comment: you mention _variable not updated_ ... which variable? Also how do you know some of these lines are _OK_?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with expected and actual output?

Comment: The problem was the variable HermesStatus. It seems that you cannot put instructions inside a variable while using this ssh syntax. What I had to do to solve the issue is execute the code (without the `` ) and send the result to a file saved on host server, then proceed to a tail-1 to retrieve the value of the execution inside that variable.